# SCORM Cross Domain, SCO-Fetcher, or any other solution

Tags: cross-domain, scorm, scorm1.2

Trying to find a solution to this, we have our LMS Server, and content servers all across the US, so the user gets their content from the closest location.

[image: Current Scenario]

I've come across a solution using SCO-Fetcher, mentioned in these two links below and illustrated below, but I cannot find any information on how to implement a similar solution.

here: http://elearningrandomwalk.blogspot.com/2006/08/sco-fetcher.html

and here: http://www.adlnet.gov/Technologies/scorm/SCORMSDocuments/SCORM%20Resources/ADL_CrossDomainScripting_1_0.pdf

[image: Solution]

If anyone has any thoughts or information regarding this, it would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work for a content provider who has had to interface with a lot of different LMSs and cross-domain has always been a painful issue.

The document you linked to not-withstanding, SCORM doesn't really cater for cross-domain at all. My experiences with cross-domain has been against the [AICC](http://www.aicc.org/) standard. In the past we've used a signed java applet to perform the cross-domain communications, but currently we are using a little hidden [flash](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/)* SWF file which we talk to via javascript. This requires the LMS to have a crossdomain.xml file installed on their web server to allow the communication, which some of our customers balk at.

* Our product heavily uses flash already, so this was not an onerous requirement for us.

The solution that we are seriously considering now is a variation on the "Run-time service on Content Server" as suggested in section 4.8 of [the cross-domain scripting document](http://www.adlnet.gov/Technologies/scorm/SCORMSDocuments/SCORM%20Resources/ADL_CrossDomainScripting_1_0.pdf).

The content server would run the courseware itself, as if it were an LMS, and proxy all the API calls to the real LMS. The diagram below shows the communication paths:

[image]

Also, your launch URL wouldn't be directly to the content (e.g., `http://abc.com/content/sco.html`) but to the software application on the content server (e.g., `http://abc.com/access.php?content=sco.html&permissions=OAUTH_ID`), which would then serve the content as if it was an LMS itself.

---

Also, just came across [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-crossdomaincomm/index.html) on cross-domain communication which, while not SCORM specific, might provide some alternative ideas for implementation.

Comment: Thanks, we'll be exploring a flash solution similar to what you are currently using. Really liked the possibility of the html5 solution in the article you linked to, but am still stuck with IE7.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but thought I'd share: I had a similar situation a few years ago and settled on an [iframe hack](http://pipwerks.com/2008/11/30/iframes-and-cross-domain-security-part-2/) to get around the cross-domain restrictions. All it requires is a bit of JavaScript and HTML. It works on older browsers, including IE6.

Chuck, what solution did you wind up using?

Comment: Our IT department was able to change the domains to alleviate the problem. Thanks for all the great work on your site.